# Refer to option button in a frame activex in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, activex, worksheet

How can I refer to an option button whitin a activeX frame?

I need, e.g., to know if it is active (True) ou not (False).

In the image below, it outlines the steps I went through to get the OB's I need to reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `worksheets("Sheet1").Frame1.ActiveControl.Value`.  Change the sheet and frame references accordingly.

Comment: @Domenic But this way how do I differentiate which of the OB is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check which option button was selected, you'll need to loop through each control within the frame . . .

```
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
For Each ctrl In Worksheets("Sheet1").Frame1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "OptionButton" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl

If ctrl Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing selected!", vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox ctrl.Name & " has been selected!", vbExclamation
End If
```